# Procedure pgsql insert rows while incrementing a date depending on anther column

Tags: postgresql, procedure

I'm a beginner in postgresql (and in SQL in general), I thank you in advance for your help.

I'm trying to create a procedure to insert rows in a table with the date column (start_date) being incremented by another column (number_months). The increment starts by zero and finish at my value.
For example if my start_date is 2021-01-01 and number_months=1, then I want to have two lines, one with new_date = 2021-01-01 + 0 months hence 2021-01-01, the second one with new_date = 2021-01-01 + 1 month hence 2021-02-01.

Below is a sample of my data:

| ID_OPERATION | START_DATE | NUMBER_MONTHS | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01234 | 2121-01-01 | 1 | 15000 |
| 02345 | 2022-11-01 | 2 | 10000 |

Below is what I want:

| ID_OPERATION | NEW_DATE | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01234 | 2121-01-01 | 15000 |
| 01234 | 2121-02-01 | 15000 |
| 02345 | 2022-11-01 | 10000 |
| 02345 | 2022-12-01 | 10000 |
| 02345 | 2023-01-01 | 10000 |

Can you help me doing this?

Comment: Not clear if this is all happening on one table or not as the date column name changes. Also why not just generate the rows in the front end code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this on the fly without adding rows using [generate_series](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html):

```
CREATE TABLE series_test (
    ID_OPERATION varchar,
    START_DATE date,
    NUMBER_MONTHS integer,
    AMOUNT numeric
);

INSERT INTO series_test
    VALUES ('01234', '2121-01-01', 1, 15000),
    ('02345', '2022-11-01', 2, 10000);

SELECT
    id_operation,
    generate_series(start_date, start_date + (number_months::varchar || '  month')::interval, '1 month'::interval)::date  AS new_date,
    amount
FROM
    series_test;

 id_operation |  new_date  | amount 
--------------+------------+--------
 01234        | 01/01/2121 |  15000
 01234        | 02/01/2121 |  15000
 02345        | 11/01/2022 |  10000
 02345        | 12/01/2022 |  10000
 02345        | 01/01/2023 |  10000


SELECT
    id_operation,
    generate_series(start_date, start_date + (number_months::varchar || '  month')::interval, '1 month'::interval)::date AS new_date,
    amount
FROM
    series_test
WHERE
    id_operation = '02345';

id_operation |  new_date  | amount 
--------------+------------+--------
 02345        | 11/01/2022 |  10000
 02345        | 12/01/2022 |  10000
 02345        | 01/01/2023 |  10000
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for, I didn't know this built-in function exists !